# Custom Select Input With Search on the Frontend

Tags: javascript, django

[See example here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etN7X.png)

Hello! The only thing i want to achieve here, is when you click (focus) on that input, automatically appears right below a "customized select popup" where apart from selecting an option, you can select a link and see the results quantity shown at the bottom of the select.

[Here is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOyks.png)

All i did was a select input with an input search to recreate this. but this is not as scallable as the other example. Im way more experienced with backend, thats why im having this type of issues with the front....

Im using in the frontend just HTML CSS and Vanilla JS. Backend with Django...

Any suggestion?